iRobot Root Simulator
I recently picked up the iRobot Root 1 platform to do some research work involving pen plotting and had hoped to use the simulator available at https://code.irobot.com/.
However, I didn't realize that you can't copy/paste Python code into it (there is a 'Level 3' for Python coding, however you have to drag and drop each code block in and there is no capability to type directly on the web app or the phone app).  I understand it is made for STEM teaching, however I really liked the platform for the direction my research is going and had hoped to be able to use the simulator without having to manually drag and drop each and every command.
Is anybody aware if it is possible to use the simulator for more than just the 'basic' usage?  It is nice that it has the drawing capabilities baked in with all the Python commands specific to the platform - I'd rather not have to reinvent the wheel with Gazebo if necessary.
